# Typescript accepts null values when type set is non-nullable

Tags: typescript

I would like to know why the following code accepts null in typescript:

> [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%2F%2F%20Not%20sure%20why%20null%20is%20accepted%20here%20when%20I've%20specified%20number%20as%20the%20type%0D%0Aconst%20foo%20%3D%20()%3A%20number%20%3D%3E%201%20%7C%7C%20null%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Even%20when%20enforcing%20non-nullable%0D%0Aconst%20foo2%20%3D%20()%3A%20NonNullable%3Cnumber%3E%20%3D%3E%201%20%7C%7C%20null%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Here%20tough%2C%20it%20works%3A%20null%20is%20not%20a%20number%0D%0Aconst%20foo3%20%3D%20(i%3A%20number)%3A%20number%20%3D%3E%20i%20%7C%7C%20null)

```
// Not sure why null is accepted here when I've specified number as the type
const foo = (): number => 1 || null

// Even when enforcing non-nullable
const foo2 = (): NonNullable<number> => 1 || null

// Here tough, it works: null is not a number
const foo3 = (i: number): number => i || null
```

Seems to be the same with `undefined`

Comment: For 1 & 2: `1 || null` is known by the compiler to be `1` and so the type is `number`, not `number | null`.  For 3: you need to turn on the `--strictNullChecks` compiler option on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mistyped your functions. To type `foo` as `() => number` and to define it as returning `null`, you should write that:

```
const foo
  : () => number // type def
  = () => null;  // function def
```

With strict null checks enabled, this [throws an error](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20foo%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20number%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20null%3B), as expected.